# Laravel: filter and group by based on created_at and sum the costs

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Base on below table

[image]

I want to get all the records `grouped by` months on `created_at` column and `sum` the `cost` of each month.

I hope I could explained it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
$monthlyCosts = DB::table('my_table')
            ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y') as month, SUM(cost) as total_cost")
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->get();
```